# Python scikit-learn: How do I convert decision tree leaves to dummy variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, dummy-variable

I am using scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier to build a decision tree.  Assume that a given decision tree has 6 leaf/terminal nodes (A, B, C, D, E and F).  I now want to assign the original records coded as to which leaf/terminal node they would belong to (think of it as a form of feature engineering).

I would prefer not to score the records directly, but instead to build a collection of dummy variables from a variety of trees into a feature engineering pipeline.

Does anyone know of any easy approach for doing this?

Comment: An example is given here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py. It uses GradientBoostingClassifier though but you can take the idea.

Comment: Now THIS is positively brilliant!!!  Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar is implemented under `ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding`. Note that `n_estimators` denotes the number of decision trees.

See docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding.html).

Comment: Thanks very much, I will look into it.